# Templavoila: section and container are removing my divs

Tags: typo3, templavoila

I want to map a FCE and my structure looks like this:

```
| ROOT (div INNER)
 --|EL
 --|SC (div INNER)
 ----|CO (div OUTER)
 ------|EL (div INNER)
 ------|EL (div INNER)
 ------|EL (div INNER)
```

**Problem No. 1:**

If I map the container with OUTER or INNER on my section element nothing changes. I always get the `<div>` in the frontend. If I map it on `<div class="item">` this div disappears in the frontend. Therefore I added the additonal `div` to retain `<div class="item">` in the frontend output.

```
<div> <!--root -->
   <div class="wrapper">
       <h1>heading</h1> <!--element before section -->
       <div class="another-wrapper-element"> <!-- section -->
          <div> <!-- container: additional element **(problem no. 1)** -->
              <div class="item">
                  <div class="heading"> <!-- element 1 -->
                  <div class="description"> <!-- element 2 -->
          </div>
          <div class="clearer"></div> <!-- **problem no.2** -->
```

**Problem No. 2:**

All elements in the section below the container disappears in the frontend. In this case the `<div class="clearer"></div>` is missing.

What can I do against disappearing divs in the frontend? How do I map these correctly?

**Full HTML code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- FCE Team Container -->
<div>
    <div class="team-container-wrapper">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <div class="team-container">
            <div>
                <div class="team-member">
                    <div class="team-member-left">
                        <img src="img/some-picture.jpg" width="158" height="218" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="team-member-right">
                        <div class="team-member-name">some name</div>
                        <div class="team-member-tel">T: <span class="team-member-tel-content">012323445</span></div>
                        <div class="team-member-mobile">M: <span class="team-member-mobile-content">1232143241</span></div>
                        <div class="team-member-email">E: <span class="team-member-email-content"><a href="mailto:email@world.com">email@world.com</a></span></div>
                        <div class="team-member-history">
                            <p>
                                Some text:<br />
                                <span class="team-member-history-content">info</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearer"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearer"></div>
                <div class="team-container-bottom"><img src="img/team-container-bottom.png" width="50" height="9" alt="" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I never had a problem of hiding div in templavoila. Here are some tips and hints.
`INNER` means that the tag you map will be untouched and only the conent will be replaced. `OUTER` means that the tag itself will be removed too and is not shown in the output. 
Please note that the root element is handled in an other way. OUTER means there that the element will bis displayed and INNER means that the element will be removed.

In your case, you need two FCEs to get this. One contains the container wich holds all items, and one contains the item.

First FCE:

- root element is the first `<div class="team-container-wrapper">` mapped with `OUTER` because you want that element in frontend
- create node header and map to `H2`
- create node "Container for conent elements" and map to `<div class="team-container">` mode is `INNER` because you want the tag in the output

Second FCE:

- root element is `<div class="team-member">` mode `OUTER`
- add nodes for name, tel,. mobile, email and so on and map to same samed div, all `INNER`

Comment: The posted HTML is not my real HTML. It is only an example. In real the tags are all closed and as valid as an FCE can be. I could post the real HTML if you would like.

Comment: I added it to my question.